# GWT application on Facebook

Tags: facebook, gwt, libgdx

How can I publish my GWT application on Facebook?

EDITED:
Facebook requires from the application to have some FacebookSDK configuration in `<body>` tag on index.html page.

The GWT-generated index.html doesn't contain the `<body>` tag at all, (it has `<bodies>` instead o_O ).

How do I do that?

I tried to add these lines to the `<bodies>` tag and upload app to facebook, but when I click "next" on App QuickStart page I get "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can." Facebook popup.

The app is generated by libgdx and works perfectly in browser on my own server.
Is there better way to publish GWT app?

There are some docs and question here and there, but it looks like they are related to old approach. Thanks!

Comment: _“But now application should be hosted on Facebook”_ - by your/your companies/clients own requirements, or what exactly do you mean? And what _type_ of Facebook app do you mean in the first place?

Comment: That's a pure html (GWT) application, it is a game. The goal is to publish it on Facebook, that is it. If I don't understand your question right, I would be grateful for the link where I can read more on facebook app types.

Comment: Well _you_ must have had something specific in mind already when you say, _“But now application should be hosted on Facebook and it requires […]”_, no? If that’s not coming from that you already decided how you want to embed your app, then where does it come from?

Comment: You are most likely looking for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/hosting

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.
On the facebook QuickStarts page https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/{app id here }/?platform=canvas
It says: "For simple applications, you may upload your application to Facebook's servers, instead of using a third-party web hosting service."

And there is a way to upload html assets in zip archive, so when I wrote "app should be hosted on facebook" I meant usage of this feature. Sorry for being hazy.

Comment: `Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.` may be problem from Facebook side

Comment: I checked one of my old `dist`(ready for deploy) folder of html module, `index.html` file contains `<body>` tag ??

Comment: I listed the GWT-generated file with facebook SDK code here:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/Y2NLb9XP
It is only <bodies> tag in it, no <body>.

The facebook's "Something went wrong." Is still there, for about a week now. I think they would've been fixed it by now. I'll try to contact support.